# Python, card game, AttributeError

Tags: python, class, oop, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a card game "fool". But when I run programm, I'm getting an AttributeError:

> Enter amount of players: 1
>   Players: player1's contains:
>
> Hand value: 0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       print(player)   File "C:\Users\kozus\Desktop\fool\fool\Hand.py", line 38, in **str**
>       text += "\nHand value: " + str(self.getValue())   File "C:\Users\kozus\Desktop\fool\fool\Hand.py", line 20, in getValue
>       result += self.card.cardPoints(self)   File "C:\Users\kozus\Desktop\fool\fool\Card.py", line 8, in cardPoints
>       if self.rank in ["10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]: AttributeError: 'Hand' object has no attribute 'rank'

That's my code:
    from random import shuffle

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def getRank(self):
        return self.rank

    def cardPoints(self):
        # Rerturns amount points for some card
        if self.rank in ["10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]:
            if self.rank == "A":
                # 11 points for ace
                return 11
            else:
                # 10 points for 10, jack, queen или king
                return 10
        else:
            # Amount points for any other card
            return ["6", "7", "8", "9"].index(self.rank) + 6

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.rank, self.suit)

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.cards = []
        self.card = Card

    def addCard(self, card):
        # Add card in hand
        self.cards.append(card)

    def getValue(self):
        # Amount points in hand
        result = 0
        # Amount aces in hand
        aces = 0

        for card in self.cards:
            result += self.card.cardPoints(self)

            # If ace in hand then we increasing amount of aces in hand
            if card.getRank() == "A":
                aces += 1

        # Count aces like 1 or 11 points
        if result + aces * 10 <= 21:
            result += aces * 10

        return result

    def __str__(self):
        text = "%s's contains:\n" % self.name

        for card in self.cards:
            text += str(card) + " "

        text += "\nHand value: " + str(self.getValue())

        return text

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ranks = ["6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"] # Ranks
        suits = ["D", "C", "H", "S"] # Suits
        self.cards = [Card(r, s) for r in ranks for s in suits] # Generating deck, consists of 36 cards
        shuffle(self.cards)

    def dealCard(self):
        # Card handing over function
        self.cards.pop()

amount_players = int(input("Enter amount of players: "))
deck = Deck() # Creating deck

i = 0

# Creating players
players = [Hand("player{0}".format(i + 1)) for i in range(amount_players)]

print("Players: ")

for player in players:
    # Printing players
    print(player)

for player in players:
    while i < 6:
        # Distrbuting 6 card per player
        player.addCard(deck.dealCard())
        i += 1

for player in players:
    print(player)
```

Is anybody nows how fix it?

Comment: As a sidenote: your card scoring is far too bulky, try `def cardPoints(self):` + `try:     return int(self.rank)` + `except:  return 11 if self.rank == "A" else 10`

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need the `card` attribute in `Hand`, so you should remove the initialization from the `Hand` constructor.  All the cards are already stored in `cards`.

This will then result in this error:

```
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 43, in getValue
    result += self.card.cardPoints(self)
AttributeError: 'Hand' object has no attribute 'card'
```

Here, the problem is that you do not use the `card` loop iteration variable because you look it up in the object, using `self`.  The `cardPoints` method also does not take any argument (except the implicit `self` parameter), so let's fix that as well:

```
        for card in self.cards:
            result += card.cardPoints()
```

This will get you past the initial error.

After that, you will have to change the `dealCard` method to actually return the card popped from the deck because the `dealCard` method currently returns `None`, having no `return` statement at all.

Comment: I had just debugged it and then saw Florian's answer. My code has those changes mentioned plus I removed the global `i` variable. ### THOU SHALT NEVER USE A GLOBAL `i` ### is a commandment passed down from our programming fore-fathers for future generations to never forget.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Change this line:
result += self.card.cardPoints(self)
# to this:
result += card.cardPoints()
```

You don't need to pass object instance(self) to `cardPoints. And why do you have this:

```
self.card = Card
```

There is no need for this, all you are doing is making `self.card` a class not an object.